# Highcharts in Yii2

Tags: highcharts, yii2

Do you know where the source code location of this in Yii2? I have installed highcharts via composer.

[image]

Because I want to add a list on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add another option in list

Comment: Yes, I want to add another option @Deep3015

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **vendor** directory.

So if you are using "**miloschuman\yii2-highcharts-widget**" and you installed it using **composer**, try looking at **vendor\miloschuman\yii2-highcharts-widget** directory.

Same goes with other vendors like "**yiisoft\yii2**" and others, they are also in the **vendor** directory.

Another piece of advice. If you are planning on modifying these source code on the vendor directory, don't. It is not advisable since when you run another **composer update** all the changes you've made on that source code will be overwritten. Just fork that package and create your own package so that it won't be overwritten once you run **composer update**.

Answer (score 0):

see here for more details [Exporting Buttons](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
      text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 2010
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Installation',
      data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
      name: 'Manufacturing',
      data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
      name: 'Sales & Distribution',
      data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
      name: 'Project Development',
      data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
      name: 'Other',
      data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }]
  });


  Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Additional Button',
    onclick: function() {
      alert('OK');
      /*call custom function here*/
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

Comment: @r34627673 through program you are not able to get